# runtotals extension of concordion and its customization of its report

Tags: markdown, junit4, concordion

I would like to customize concordion report. I am using an Extension that called Run Totals.

```
@Extensions(value = { RunTotalsExtension.class })
```

I have an main md file with the tests listed

Tests Report

```
[Scenario 1: Send a GET(getall) for admin] (scenarios/getallSC1.md "c:run")    

[Scenario 2: Send a GET(getall) for admin] (scenarios/getallSC2.md "c:run")    

[Scenario 3: Send a GET(getall) for comp] (scenarios/getallSC3.md "c:run")
```

The output of that run looks like this :

```
1       welcome  sc1 GET (Success: 20, Failures: 1, Exceptions: 1);
2       welcome  sc1 GET (Success: 12, Failures: 1, Exceptions: 1);
3       welcome  sc1 GET (Success: 5, Failures: 0);
```

I would like to get the totals on a separate column. How can I customize the report to get the totals per say category. And on the front end I would like to display them in a separate column

Notice this page 
http://concordion.github.io/concordion/latest/spec/common/results/runTotals/RunTotals.html?

I am trying to count the success and failures and put them in separate columns as shown in the above link

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of that extension. I'm glad you're enjoying using it!

To be honest, the best way to get the output formatted the way you want is to make a copy of the extension (it's only one file) and modify the writeText method. I'll make a change so that the writeText method is protected and can be overwritten. You can call it something different (like 'RunTotalsInColumns') and use it the same way you use runtotals.

Here is the file:

https://github.com/concordion/concordion-run-totals-extension/blob/master/src/main/java/org/concordion/ext/runtotals/RunTotalsExtension.java

Good luck,

Tim